# Had Ravan tried would he have been able to lift Angad's feet?

Tags: ramayana, rama, ramcharitmanas

In the Ramayana, there is an incident in which Rama sends Angad as his associate for a final try of avoiding war.

Then seeing Ravan's ego and attitude Angad challenges all the warriors in his palace that if anyone would be able to lift his feet from ground, then Ram would accept defeat and leave. As we know, no one was able to lift the feet of Angad and in the last Ravan gets up to lift his feet. Just when he is about to grab his feet, Angad pulls back and asks him to grab the feet of Ram so that he would forgive him.

**So, if Ravan would have tried to lift Angad's feet, would he have been able to lift his feet or he would have failed like others?**

**Also, is there anything else we can understand from this incident in Ramayana?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in another answer, this episode does not occur in Sri Valmiki Ramayana but in Sri Ramacharitmanas of Gosvami Tulasidas.

Following is the [original text](https://www.ramcharitmanas.iitk.ac.in/ramcharitmanas?tid=6&tid_1=11&tid_2=8) with hindi translations from Gita-press gorakhpur's edition (english translations are mine) from **LankA-KAnda** which contains this episode:

> **6.34**
>
> *जौं मम चरन सकसि सठ टारी । फिरहिं रामु सीता मैं हारी ।।*
>
> [अङ्गदने कहा—]
> अरे मूर्ख! यदि तू मेरा चरण हटा सके तो श्रीरामजी लौट जायँगे, मैं सीताजीको हार गया।
>
> Angad said: If you can move my leg than Lord Shri Rama would go back without >Shrimati Sitadevi and we would lose.
>
> *सुनहु सुभट सब कह दससीसा । पद गहि धरनि पछारहु कीसा ।।*
>
> रावणने कहा—हे सब वीरो! सुनो, पैर पकड़कर बंदरको पृथ्वीपर पछाड़ दो ।।⁠५⁠।|
>
> Ravana said: Listen everyone! Knock down this monkey by pulling his leg!
>
> **6.35**
>
> *कपि बल देखि सकल हियँ हारे । उठा आपु कपि कें परचारे ।।*
>
> अङ्गदका बल देखकर सब हृदयमें हार गये। तब अङ्गदके ललकारनेपर रावण स्वयं उठा।
>
> Seeing Angad's strength everybody accepted defeat. And then being challenged by Angad, Ravana himself got up.

Here the word used is *परचारे* (parchAre) which would mean that Angad challenged or shouted Ravana to come

> *गहत चरन कह बालिकुमारा । मम पद गहें न तोर उबारा ।।*
>
> जब वह अङ्गदका चरण पकड़ने लगा, तब बालिकुमार अङ्गदने कहा—मेरा चरण पकड़नेसे तेरा बचाव नहीं होगा! ।।⁠१⁠।।
>
> When he started holding Angad's feet, Angad said: you won't be saved by holding onto my leg. :-)

There is no where mentioned that Angad removed his feet, but instead he humiliated Ravana

> *गहसि न राम चरन सठ जाई । सुनत फिरा मन अति सकुचाई ।।
>
> भयउ तेजहत श्री सब गई । मध्य दिवस जिमि ससि सोहई ।।*
>
> अरे मूर्ख! तू जाकर श्रीरामजीके चरण क्यों नहीं पकड़ता? यह सुनकर वह मनमें बहुत ही सकुचाकर लौट गया।
> उसकी सारी श्री जाती रही। वह ऐसा तेजहीन हो गया जैसे मध्याह्नमें चन्द्रमा दिखायी देता है ।।⁠२⁠।।
>
> Why don't you hold on to Lord Shri Rama's feet? Listening to this Ravana was very embarassed.
> He became bereft of all lustre just like moon loses its lustre at mid-day.
>
> *सिंघासन बैठेउ सिर नाई । मानहुँ संपति सकल गँवाई ।।
>
> जगदातमा प्रानपति रामा । तासु बिमुख किमि लह बिश्रामा ।।*
>
> वह सिर नीचा करके सिंहासनपर जा बैठा। मानो सारी सम्पत्ति गँवाकर बैठा हो।
> श्रीरामचन्द्रजी जगत्भरके आत्मा और प्राणोंके स्वामी हैं। उनसे विमुख रहनेवाला शान्ति कैसे पा सकता है? ।।⁠३⁠।।
>
> With head hung low he went and sat on his throne as if he has lost all his wealth.

So here it seems, Ravana didn't even tried lifting Angad's legs but was humiliated that a King of his stature is stooping low to touch the feet of just an insignificant servant of Lord Sri Rama, so what will happen when Lord Sri Rama himself arrives!

> Lord Shri Ramachandra is the soul of the world and master of all living beings, how can one be peaceful without being friendly towards him?
>
> *उमा राम की भृकुटि बिलासा । होइ बिस्व पुनि पावइ नासा ।।
>
> तृन ते कुलिस कुलिस तृन करई । तासु दूत पन कहु किमि टरई ।।*
>
> [शिवजी कहते हैं—] हे उमा! जिन श्रीरामचन्द्रजीके भ्रूविलास (भौंहके इशारे) - से विश्व उत्पन्न होता है और फिर नाशको प्राप्त होता है;
>
> Oh Uma! Just by the movement of the eyebrows of Lord Shri Ramachandra this whole universe is created and destroyed;
>
> जो तृणको वज्र और वज्रको तृण बना देते हैं (अत्यन्त निर्बलको महान् प्रबल और महान् प्रबलको अत्यन्त निर्बल कर देते हैं), उनके दूतका प्रण, कहो, कैसे टल सकता है? ।।⁠४⁠।।
>
> That Lord Sri Rama who can make the weak very strong and the strong very weak, how then can his servant's/messenger's vow be nullified?

Here it explains clearly that one who is a servant of Lord Shri Rama how can his vow be nullified that simply means **even if Ravana would have tried it Angad's feet would not have budged**

> ..
>
> *जातुधान अंगद पन देखी । भय ब्याकुल सब भए बिसेषी ।।*
>
> अंगदका प्रण [सफल] देखकर सब राक्षस भयसे अत्यन्त ही व्याकुल हो गये ।।⁠७⁠।।
>
> All the Rakshasas became very fearful seeing that Angad's Vow was successful.

So at the end we see that its clearly written that Angad's vow ( पन /  praN) was successful.

1. So to answer your first question:

   ***No Ravana couldn't have moved it even if he would have tried***.
2. To answer your second question whether we can understand anything else from this episode?

   One thing i can understand is that how a servant should do service to his master. Angad like Hanuman did more than what was expected of him, one he tossed Ravana's helmet (in previous verses 6.31 to 6.33) to Ram's feet, he humiliated all of the Rakshasas including Ravana which is very important in a battle i.e. to lower the morale of the opponent.

   Another thing we can learn is he showed that he has full faith in Lord Shri Rama and hence he had the strength to be bold enough in front of all the Rakshasas and that is why nobody could even move him.

   Another thing is that a servant should never hear blaspheme of his master, if he has to hear, he should behave just like Angad and make the blasphemer pay for their impudence and thus silence their blasphemy. :-)

Comment: Thanks for making this issue clear that this is from Ramacharitamanas.  I am not aware of this fact.@Prakash K

Answer (score 6):

Angada's  challenging all of the warriors in Ravana's palace  to lift his feet from ground, ***is not from Valmiki Ramayana***.

The following is what transpired in [that episode](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/yuddha/sarga41/yuddha_41_frame.htm), after delivering of Sri Rama's message by Angada:

> ततः स रोष ताम्र अक्षह् शशास सचिवांस् तदा | गृह्यताम् एष दुर्मेधा
>   वध्यताम् इति च असकृत् || ६-४१-८४
>
> Then, the enraged Ravana repeatedly commanded his attendants, saying:
>   "Let this stupid monkey be seized and put to death."
>
> रावणस्य वचह् श्रुत्वा दीप्त अग्नि सम तेजसः | जगृहुस् तम् ततो घोराश्
>   चत्वारो रजनी चराः || ६-४१-८५
>
> Hearing Ravana's words, four terrible demons seized Angada who, in his
>   splendour, resembled a blazing torch.
>
> ग्राहयाम् आस तारेयह् स्वयम् आत्मानम् आत्मना | बलम् दर्शयितुम् वीरो
>   यातु धान गणे तदा || ६-४१-८६
>
> Then, the prudent and heroic Angada the son of Tara voluntarily
>   allowed himself to be seized, in order to display his prowess before
>   the host of demons.
>
> स तान् बाहु द्वये सक्तान् आदाय पतगान् इव | प्रासादम् शैल सम्काशम्
>   उत्पापात अन्गदस् तदा || ६-४१-८७
>
> Then, seizing like unto birds those attendants clung to his arms,
>   Angada leapt on to the palace that resembled like a mountain.
>
> तेस्योत्पतनवेगेन निर्धूतास्तत्र राक्षसाः | भुमौ निपतिताह् सर्वे राक्षस
>   इन्द्रस्य पश्यतः || ६-४१-८८
>
> All those four demons were shaken out by Angada's impetuous leap and
>   fell on the ground there under the eyes of their king.
>
> Thereafter, the glorious Angada the son of Vali ascended the roof of
>   Ravana's palace, which equaled the summit of a mountain in height.
>
> पफाल च तदाक्रान्तं दशग्रीवस्य पश्यतः | पुरा हिमवतः शृङ्गं वज्रेणेव
>   विदारितम् ६-४१-९०
>
> That roof of the palace, trampled by Angada, crumbled - as a peak of
>   Himalayan range was shattered long ago by lightening - before Ravana's
>   gaze.
>
> Thereafter, the glorious Angada the son of Vali ascended the roof of
>   Ravana's palace, which equaled the summit of a mountain in height.